# User Community Nickname

Tags: user-record

Community Nickname has to be unique across all users? or it has to be unique within a org? As far as I know, username has to be unique across all Salesforce users in the world. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Yes your salesforce username has to be globally unique. I would think the Community Nickname is only unique across your org.

You might also want to review this thread [Handling Community Nickname field for Customer Portal registration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305/handling-community-nickname-field-for-customer-portal-registration)

Answer (score 2):

Within the org.  That's what you're authenticating into.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. Nickname has to be unique within the org but username has to be unique across all the orgs world-wide. Am I right?